# Why can't I use document in Brackets?

Tags: javascript, document, adobe-brackets

I'm using the Brackets IDE and I tried basic JS. Using the object document sends me to an error saying

> "ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]",

I can't find out why is this error happening since it works perfectly in dreamweaver, does anyone know why is this happening in Brackets? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Parrafos</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>a</p>
        <p>aa</p>
        <p id="special">especial</p>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="javascript" src="parrafos.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function parrafo(texto, id) {
    document.getElementById(id).textContent = texto;
}

parrafo("Hola qué tal", "especial");
```

Comment: It really does not make sense to load two different versions of jQuery. One is just going to overwrite the other.

Comment: `type="javascript"` — That is not a valid value for the `type` attribute … and the HTML spec says you should omit the `type` attribute entirely for traditional JavaScript.

Comment: i dont know why u get that error, but i noticed that you dont have "especial" id in your HTML. change it to special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document` is not part of JavaScript, it is part of the browser DOM.

Whatever linter (e.g. JSHint, JSLint, ESLint) you have configured Brackets to use to test you code with hasn't been configured to assume the presense of global variables that exist when you run the code through a script element in an HTML document.

Consult the documentation for whichever linter you are using to find out how to do that (likely this will either be a configuration file in the root of your project directory or a specially formatted comment at the top of your JS file).

Answer (score -2):

`"ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]"` Means that every variables should be declared, in top of your code state: `var document;` or disable lint from checking  `[no-undef]`

**UPDATE**

After the comments, if you want to pick the first option you can write:
`var document = window.document;`
to suppress the message and be clear

Comment: I didn't downvote but anyone who've written javascript for the browser knows what `document` is. Have you only worked in node.js? It's amazing for me to see a javascript programmer who haven't written code for the browser.

Comment: @slebetman The world of JavaScript today requires to be **clear** even in things that everyone knows.

Comment: Redeclaring a variable that has already been declared is not *clear*.

Comment: @Quentin declared by the browser not by the programmer, i think that kobe points to be clear for mates not for comps

Comment: @dotnetandsqldevelop — `var document; document.getElementById…` isn't clear. It makes it look like `document` is `undefined` so you can't call methods on it. Unlike, for instance, actually configuring the linter with something like `/* global document */`

Comment: @kobe You CANNOT declare `document` it may be OK sometimes in simple test code but it is buggy. For example, if your code gets used by something like browserify or webpack or YUI compiler and is wrapped in an IIFE declaring `var document` just made your code stopped working because it is no longer pointing to the document object but a local variable.